# Center two UIViews of different size horizontally

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have the following wireframe:

[image]

I need to add the "Don't have an account yet? Sign Up.". To do this I'll have two different UILabels, one with "Don't have an account yet?" and another with "Sign Up" so I can style them separately.

My problem is that I don't know how to center to the Superview two different labels that have different size and my grow if it's localized to a language where they take more space than english...

So the questions would be: "How do I center two UILabels with different width related to it's superview?"

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the steps:

1. Take a view that contains both of your labels and make centerx to it.
2. Pinned label 1 with all sides with greater then equal width constraint
3. and follow step 2 for label2.

Here is the visual presentation of it...

[image]

Comment: By the way it's not necessary to set Width and Heigh constraint for labels.

Comment: I just set width constraint not height ...I just want to say that this is another way....your way in above is also correct...but by this way you can also done the same thing

Answer (score 6):

You should put them into container UIView make it flexible width (for ex. >= 10) and center it.